# UIInterfaceOrientation rotate along with the Hearder

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiinterfaceorientation

When I rotate the simulator from portrait to landscape, the header is not rotating. I want to rotate the header along with the view rotation using UIInterfaceOrientation.[image]

Comment: Anyone please give me a guidance to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@renuga i think you need to implement this method in your view controller.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        return YES;
    if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
        return YES;
    return NO;
}
```

go to IB and click on the arrow shown below.

[image]

and there you need to adjust the position of your tab bar

Comment: @robin:Thank You so much for your quick response.The above code rotates the statusbar(only) in according to the orientation.It's not rotate the header i mean(it's may be navigation bar or Toolbar).

Comment: it will rotate the all the UIView objects in the IB can you show your IB snap shot

Comment: Please refer my question i have edit the question and add my InterfaceBuilder screenshot.Thank You

Comment: @robin:Hai robin when i rotate the simulator from portrait(in portrait mode it shows Toolbar)to Landscape mode it doesn't  shows the Toolbar.I don't know why it comes like this.Please help me to do this.THank You

Comment: Hai Robin..When i click the arrow you have specified in your screendhot,it shows the Toolbar image only in portrait mode and it doesn't shows the Toolbar in landscape mode (position of the Toolbar automatically changed when it goes to Landscape mode).In Portrait mode:   X:0 y:0 W:320 H:44  In landscape mode  X:0 y:-160 W:480 H:44 .why this problem occurs please help me to solve this.Thank You

Comment: Hai Robin..could you please guide me to do this.

Comment: @Robin:i'm really sorry for asking doubt on your company site.could you please clear my doubt